# "UPDATE WHERE NOT LIKE? "

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I am trying to append strings to a field if they do not already exist with:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE gals4 SET tags = CONCAT(tags, '$instag') WHERE id = '$instagnum' AND tags NOT LIKE '$instag'");
```

This just appends to 'tags' regardless of weather it exists in the field or not. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the arguments you are passing?  `$instag` specifically?

Comment: Echo out your SQL, and make sure it looks like what you're expecting. And then see if run properly in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you must put the character % at the beginning and end of the match string:

```
 "AND tags NOT LIKE '%$instag%'"
```

However, you should be aware that this is a *terrible* way to store data in an SQL database.  There are at least three problems:

1. If you have tags that embed other tags ("cat" and "scat" for instance) you will find the wrong records unless you write very complicated comma-based searches.
2. These searches can never be indexed and will therefore become very slow as the number of records grows.
3. You cannot verify the tags used against a list of allowed tags, guarantee that only allowed tags are in the database, or easily present a list of existing or allowed tags.

The correct solution is to add at least one table to your database, called something like gals_tags, with columns galid and tag.  Insert *one record* per tag into this table.  If a gal has more than one tag, add one record for each tag.

Comment: Thanks Larry, i thought it would be something simple like that, i could have stared at that for hours and not seen, also thanks for the advice, this is my first day with HTML PHP SQL so this is just a learning exercise, i was going to go with the comma thing :), i can already see that efficiency is important when it comes to SQL databases, its already slowing down :).

Comment: This isn't really an HTML or PHP issue, but rather one of databases.  I would advise tackling the issues separately (that is, getting the database designed and tested through an SQL console) before coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need another variable $instagwildcard which would be $instag but with a % after (and possibly before) $instag

As written, your select is looking for a string that is not an exact match to $instag - and I assume you are looking to also exclude strings that contain $instag somewhere in the string rather than an exact match....

```
$instagwildcard = "%" . $instag . "%";
mysql_query("UPDATE gals4 SET tags = CONCAT(tags, '$instag') WHERE id = '$instagnum' AND tags NOT LIKE '$instagwildcard'");
```

But I also agree with Larry's comment.